# Docker invalid tag

Tags: docker, github-actions

I m trying to build a image using github actions workflow

But the tag is invalid for some reason

```
  - name: Build and push
    id: docker_build
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
    with:
      context: .
      file: ./Dockerfile
      push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
      tags: gcr.io/af-image/docker-image-test:refs/heads/master
```

It raises:

```
invalid tag "gcr.io/af-image/docker-image-test:refs/heads/master": invalid reference format
```

Any idea why?

Here's how I m building the tag :

```
- name: Prepare docker tag
    id: prep
    run: |
      set -x
      VERSION=${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}
      TAG=gcr.io/af-image/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:${VERSION#"${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}-"}
      echo ::set-output name=tag::${TAG}
```

It was bcs i forgot to give a tag to this branch
VERSION=${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}

Answer (score 0):

A tag cannot contain `/`. Try using tags: `gcr.io/af-image/docker-image-test:master` instead.

Comment: Yeah so I was getting the tags for the master branch and forgot to actually give one and push it to remote